# Tracking order popup not working

Tags: shipment-tracking

We use different suppliers to deliver our orders.
But when I enter the correct tracking number when shipping the order, the order tracking pop up does not work.

Is it possible to redirect directly to the currect trackingpage of the supplier, instead of showing this popup?

See this:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I am not sure check consolve may be it's conflict only

Comment: @Kothari Thanks! Is it possible to redirect directly to the currect trackingpage of the supplier, instead of showing this popup?

Comment: Is it possible But you should have that page

Comment: @Kothari Thanks, I do have these pages and url's, because I use already a rule for that in the shipping email. But where can I edit the page?

Comment: Update your phtml

Comment: The tracking URLs and or API access is for US only afaik. I think, this will be the problem.
EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that you want your URLs get rewriten. Well as Kothari said, rewrite your PHTMLs for the URLs.

Comment: @Kothari Thanks! What phtml file do i need to edit for this?

Comment: I don't have that module so sorry no idea about files

Comment: @Kothari Thanks, I use the default Magento method. So it should be a default phtml file. How can I find out which one I need?

Comment: It's not a magento default try to enable template hints and check for backend

Answer (score 0):

Open in your admin panel **Sales > Shipments** there you might find the tracking number for each order, then open the [UPS website and test](https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking?HTMLVersion=5.0&error_carried=true&tracknums_displayed=5&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&loc=en_US&InquiryNumber1=9400110200864768884042&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes/) (if it's your case), in my case the number wasn't valid.

[image: Magento2 Sales Shipments]